# How to get selected value from dropdown in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

i set dropdown menu in page but how to get selectd value.
Code that i used

```
<ion-item>
                    <ion-label>MemberType</ion-label>
                    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedvalue" #item >
                    <ion-option *ngFor="let item of items" value="{{item.value}}" checked="{{item.checked}}">{{item.text}}</ion-option>
                    </ion-select>
                </ion-item>


items: Array<{ value: number, text: string, checked: boolean }> = [];

    this.items.push({ value: 1, text: 'Super Distributor', checked: false });
    this.items.push({ value: 2, text: 'Distributor', checked: false });
    this.items.push({ value: 3, text: 'Retailer', checked: false });
    this.items.push({ value: 4, text: 'End User', checked: false });
```

Answer (score 5):

By doing this:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>MemberType</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedvalue">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let item of items" value="{{item.value}}" checked="{{item.checked}}">{{item.text}}</ion-option>
     </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

You're using `ngModel` to create a `two directional` binding between the `select` and the `selectedvalue` property (which I assume is declared in the `component` of that page). So the selected value will be in your `selectedvalue` variable.

You can add this to your page to see that:

```
<p>Selected Value: {{ selectedvalue }}</p>
```